# Is question mark in URL part of query string?

Tags: url, query-string, rfc3986, rfc1738

TL;TR: Is (first) question mark in URL part of query or is is just a separator followed by query?

The [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738), section 3.3, suggests that the "?" (question mark) is not part of the query string, but just separates it from the path:

```
http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>
```

Grammar presented in the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), Appendix A., also indicate the "?" is not part of the actual query string:

```
URI = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

Now, let's consider two URLs:

1. `http://server.com/api/item.json`
2. `http://server.com/api/item.json?`

Are they equivalent or distinct?

Is it valid to distinguish them and use to identify two different resources?

Comment: _“Is it valid to distinguish them and use to identify two different resources?”_ – even if it was, I would not recommend it; you never know which client will feel inclined to perform what “normalization” on such a URL.

Comment: @CBroe I sympathise with your recommendation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

- The `?` is not part of the query component.
- The URIs are not equivalent, because one has ***no* query component**, while the other one has an ***empty* query component**.

---

The URI standard ([STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66)) is currently [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

Section [6.2. Comparison Ladder](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2) describes methods how to test if URIs are possibly equivalent.

In [6.2.3. Scheme-Based Normalization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.3) it says:

> Normalization should not remove delimiters when their associated component is empty unless licensed to do so by the scheme specification.  For example, the URI `http://example.com/?` cannot be assumed to be equivalent to any of the examples above.

Where "examples above" refers to:

> ```
> http://example.com
> http://example.com/
> http://example.com:/
> http://example.com:80/
> ```

(These 4 URIs are equivalent.)

So `http://example.com/api/item.json` has no query component, while `http://example.com/api/item.json?` has an empty query component.